# 'Error: Cannot find module' after fork and patch

Tags: node.js, npm, git-fork

I forked an npm package (https://github.com/spark/particle-api-js), made some changes, used that in a project (https://github.com/RoomKit/RoomKit-Backend) and then left it for a while.

I resumed working on it today and suddenly node claims that the package is not installed. If I replace my custom repo in package.json with a version number it works just fine. In both cases the package is there in the node_modules folder.

I deleted the node_modules folder and ran `npm install`. That goes through without a problem but at runtime it still complains. What is going on?

Answer (score 6):

If you're installing from a forked package on github you are probably missing the `lib` directory for the package. NPM doesn't run a build on forked packages so it's not going to be there if you do npm install. You can verify this by going into the `node_modules` directory, finding your package's directory and checking for what's in there. Simply having a `src` folder is not enough.

One way around this is to make sure your forked repo checks in any `build` or `lib` folders.