# Next JS Can't Find Forked Node Module

Tags: npm, next.js, fork

I forked a basic audio player library and before making any changes to it, I added the GitHub url of the fork to my package.json:

```
"react-h5-audio-player": "amchfc/react-h5-audio-player"
```

Running npm install succeeds and the entire package contents appear in my node_modules.  However, when I run the server locally, I get the following error when I try to import the module:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-h5-audio-player'
```

Do I need to do anything special when using a forked module in NextJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Error: Cannot find module' after fork and patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754663/error-cannot-find-module-after-fork-and-patch)