# How to create build for forked React Native npm package

Tags: react-native, npm, build

I forked a React Native npm library `react-native-calendars` to make some changes to it. I now want to implement these changes in my project. I have installed it in my project using:

```
npm i git+<my_forked_git_repo_url>
```

This successfully added the package to my node_modules, however I still get an error in my code when I try and import `react-native-calendars` saying `Cannot find module`. After doing some research I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911500/11502399)) that I must create a build using `npm run build` and add it to the forked repository.

However, when I run `npm run build` it creates a build directory in my `ios/` directory (since I am targeting iOS). Is this expected, or should I have a new `build/` directory in the root directory? The contents of this `build/` directory include a `...-buildRequest.json`, `...-desc.xcbuild`, `...-manifest.xcbuild`, `...-targetFile.txt`, and a `BuildDescriptionCacheIndex-...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. install the original package
2. paste your changes into the package's code in node_modules
3. install `patch-package` if you don't already have it (follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package))
4. run `npx patch-package react-native-calendars`

This will create a diff between the original package and your changes. Then your changes will be applied every time you run yarn or npm.

Comment: Thanks, this does work but the files in the npm package aren't the same as in the GitHub repository. For eg the typescript files are converted to js and there are additional `.d.ts` files which make it a bit more difficult to paste changes

Comment: Could you delete everything inside the directory and paste your files in instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the `Cannot find module` error...

Comment: you may need to refactor your revision to have the same exports as the original for this to work

Comment: Yes, I was eventually able to modify the `package.json` to get it to work. Ideally I would like to find a way to do this by using my forked repo as an npm package since I want to push these changes to the `react-native-calendars` package but this will do for now!

Comment: Makes sense, glad you got it working.